# How to install imagick on PHP7 and Debian?

Tags: debian, imagick, php-7

I need to install Imagick, but I've php7 and debian. 
I tried to do this :

```
apt-get install php-imagick
```

But I've this error :

```
Unable to locate package php-imagick
```

I also tried to do this

```
apt-get install php5-imagick
```

But O think this command is to php5, an dnow I've in `/etc/php5/mods-available/` un `imagick.ini`

So is imagick is install for php7?

Answer (score 1):

Debian Buster and PHP7.3

```
sudo apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev 
sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick
pecl install imagick
```

if you don't have `pecl`
you could try to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install -y php-pear
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install -y pear
```

if above ways fail, you can alternatively download it from web and use php to install it:

```
wget -O ./go-pear.php http://pear.php.net/go-pear
php ./go-pear.php
rm ./go-pear.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Imagick is not yet released for PHP7 on Debian stable.