# Docker PHP7 CLI Debian Buster how to install package php-imagick?

Tags: php, docker, debian, imagick, debian-buster

I have a PHP-CLI [Docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/135204c0f4c7a255ee70ec82dc1133929f9676c0/7.3/buster/cli) of Debian Buster and would like to install [php-imagick](https://packages.debian.org/buster/php-imagick) package but with command:

Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y php-imagick
```

I get an error:

> Package php-imagick is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'php-imagick' has no installation candidate

running before:

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
```

did not help.

how come there is no package candidate for [php-imagick](https://packages.debian.org/buster/php-imagick)?
how to install and enable imagick extension for this PHP [Docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/135204c0f4c7a255ee70ec82dc1133929f9676c0/7.3/buster/cli)?

Dockerfile to replicate issue:

```
FROM php:7.3-buster

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y php-imagick
```

build command

```
docker build --tag testimage .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason not to, using the packages from https://deb.sury.org/ is probably a good idea. The following appears to work:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

USER root

# Get Debian up-to-date
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git \
    mariadb-client wget curl \
    ca-certificates lsb-release apt-transport-https gnupg bsdmainutils

RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
    && curl https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y php7.3 php7.3-common php7.3-cli \
    php7.3-mysql php7.3-curl php7.3-xml php7.3-mbstring \
    php7.3-intl php7.3-redis php7.3-zip \
    php7.3-imagick supervisor
```

Comment: Tested - works well. I found out also an alternative method to install in generall [imagick for Debian and PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57466720/1174405). Do you have any idea why it is  not straightforward to install that extension taking into account it is listed as an extension on Debian website?

Comment: "apt install php7.3-imagick" is pretty simple. The other ways are complex as Imagick can work with multiple versions of ImageMagic.